# Expression Changed Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

**Scenario :**

In the left side, all the unpaid bills are shown, When the user clicks a bill, it's details are shown in the right side. If the user, clicks the pay button, the bill is paid, meaning it shouldn't be in the left side. The process goes on.

**Issue :**

I managed to pay the bill and the paid bill disappears from the left side. The issue is with clicking the next bill in the left side brings this error.

> Runtime Error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current
>   value: 'false'.

**Screencast :**

[image]

**Code :**

bill-settlement.ts

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-bill-settlement',
  templateUrl: 'bill-settlement.html',
})
export class BillSettlement {
  billItem: BillDetail
  updateItem: boolean
  ...
  onBillSelected(billData: BillDetail) {
    this.billItem = billData
  }
  isUpdate(updateData: boolean) {
    this.updateItem = updateData
  }
}
```

bill-settlement.html

```
...
<page-bill-list (BillSelected)="onBillSelected($event)" [updateItem]="updateItem"></page-bill-list>
...
<page-bill-details (isUpdate)="isUpdate($event)" [billItem]="billItem"></page-bill-details>
```

bill-list.ts

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-bill-list',
  templateUrl: 'bill-list.html',
})
export class BillList {
  billItems: BillDetail[] = []
  billItem = new BillDetail()
  @Input() updateItem: boolean
  @Output() BillSelected: EventEmitter<BillDetail> = new EventEmitter<BillDetail>()
  constructor(...) {
    this.billSrv.getBills()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.billItems = data
      })
  }
  ngOnChanges(updateItem: boolean) {
    if (this.updateItem == true) {
      this.billSrv.getBills()
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.billItems = data
        })
    }
  }
  getBillDetails(item: BillDetail) {
    this.BillSelected.emit(item)
  }
}
```

bill-list.html

```
<ion-buttons>
  <button ion-button *ngFor="let item of billItems" (click)="getBillDetails(item)">Bill {{item.BillNo}}</button>
</ion-buttons>
```

bill-details.ts

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-bill-details',
  templateUrl: 'bill-details.html',
})
export class BillDetails {
  ...
  @Input() billItem: BillDetail
  @Output() isUpdate: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>()
  ...
  ngOnChanges(billItem: BillDetail) {
    this.isUpdate.emit(false) //if this part is commented
//the bills are paid but the left side is not reloaded from the second time
  }
  settleBill() {
    ...
    this.billSrv.settleBill(...).subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data) {
          this.isUpdate.emit(true) //so the bill list is reloaded
        }
        else {
          ...
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Runtime Error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current
>   value: 'false'.

This error generally happens in DEV because DEV runs extra cycles of change detection.  And this error occurs when a value has changed between the redundant cycles of change detection.  This implies that something is changing values in a more or less uncontrolled manner.  After change detection runs, values are expected to be somewhat stable until the next explicit change detection cycle.  The redundant change detection cycles in DEV catch scenarios where values are changing unexpectedly.

This generally points to a problem of how values are being propagated throughout your component, but there are scenarios where the behavior you have is what you want.  In that scenario, you can fix this error by adding

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }
```

And then use `this.cdr.detectChanges();` where your value is changing and you explicitly want to call another round of change detection.

Again, normally this error points out where you have a value changing that may cause a problem in your Production environment because the value is changing *after* the change detection cycle.  Development mode only runs a second round of change detection after the first in order to catch scenarios like this that you need to be aware of.

Hope this helps.

Technically speaking, you could add `detectChanges` after:

```
ngOnChanges(billItem: BillDetail) {
    this.isUpdate.emit(false) //if this part is commented
//the bills are paid but the left side is not reloaded from the second time
  }
```

And the problem would go away, but you probably won't want to do that.  See, `this.isUpdate.emit(false)` will fire anytime `ngOnChanges` fires.  It will also fire anytime `@Input() billItem: BillDetail` changes.  That is probably not what you want.  You probably want to move `this.isUpdate.emit(false)` somewhere else where you explicitly call it.

Comment: Thanks @tyler-jennings. This helps a lot. Fixed my issue by moving my `this.isUpdate.emit(false)` from ngOnChanges. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help.  I've been troubled by this problem more than once.

Comment: It seems to me that calling `detectChanges` within `ngOnChanges` is introducing your own `$diget` loop but without angular checking the maximum loop recursion! I suspect hitting these kind of problems is going to be quite common (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070732/angular-4-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-expression-has-changed)

Answer (score 0):

THe above error generally comes when we try to modify a value which is using during component creation.I myself encountered the same problem.
Did the below changes and resolves the error.
Hope this may help you as well.

My requirement was to insert rows in the table .row is having 2 columns ,one is input and unit.Once it gets added ,cursor should be focused/activated in INPUT field.
Did the below code changes and wallahhh.... the expression error gone

Code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
       setTimeout (() => {
        if (!isNullOrUndefined(this.input.nativeElement)) {
          this.editingActive = true;
          this.input.nativeElement.focus();
          this.input.nativeElement.click();
              }
      }
    , 0);
  }
```