# Angular 4: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

Every EventEmiiter in my child module gives this error and I can't find a fix for this.

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.`

This is what triggers my EventEmitter:

```typescript
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (changes.groupingTabValid) {
        if (changes.groupingTabValid.currentValue !== changes.groupingTabValid.previousValue) {
            this.groupingTabValidChange.emit(this.groupingTabValid);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my "main" componenent's HTML

```xml
<year-overview-grouping [definitionDetails]="definitionDetails"
                        [fixedData]="fixedData"
                        [showValidation]="showValidation"
                        [groupingTabValid]="groupingTabValid"
                        (groupingTabValidChange)="setValidators('groupingTab', $event)">

</year-overview-grouping>
```

Which calls this function

```typescript
public setValidators(validator: string, e: boolean) {
    switch (validator) {
        case "groupingTab":             
            this.groupingTabValid = e;
            break;

        case "selectionTab":
            this.selectionTabValid = e;
            break;
    }

    if (this.groupingTabValid && this.selectionTabValid) {
        this.valid = true;
    } else {
        this.valid = false;
    }
}
```

1) In a a simple explanation, what's causing this error?

2) What steps can I take to solve this?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364386/whats-the-difference-between-markforcheck-and-detectchanges/41364469#41364469

Comment: that's an interesting case, can you put up a plunker maybe? you're updating parents properties after they were checked and this is what causing the trouble - [read more here](https://hackernoon.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e#d14a), but it shouldn't be the problem if you're doing it in the `onChanges` hook.

Comment: @Maximus here's a plunker with that shows the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/cdh9ryNFqOnmnHaN8rl1
With the console open, try changing age to 18. In this particular case the `*ngIf` expression is causing the problem in the parent template

Comment: Please read the [help centre advice on tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Pretty much all your questions have tags inserted in their titles, which they shouldn't *For example, rather than writing, "JavaScript, jQuery: When should I use one or the other?" – which forces tags into the title – you can convey the same information in a conversational tone "Can I use jQuery to foo the bar on the baz, or am I stuck using plain JavaScript?"*

Comment: [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details

Answer (score 11):

Abide by the unidirectional data flow rule

Try to postpone the call to emit for one tick with a setTimeout

```js
if (changes.groupingTabValid.currentValue !== changes.groupingTabValid.previousValue) {
    setTimeout(() => this.groupingTabValidChange.emit(this.groupingTabValid), 0)
}
```

Comment: Is this really the best solution though? I have seen this solution suggested in a few places now, and it just feels like a work around.

Comment: It is a work-around and there can be better solutions out there

Answer (score 4):

Just import ChangeDetectionStrategy and then add this to your component

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-bla-bla-bla',
  templateUrl: './xxxxx'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using `setTimeout` and tell Angular that changes are about to happen after initial check.

You can inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component and use its `markForCheck` method.

```
/* ... */

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

/* ... */

if (changes.groupingTabValid.currentValue !== changes.groupingTabValid.previousValue {
  this.cdr.markForCheck();
  this.groupingTabValidChange.emit(this.groupingTabValid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting to look at this exception type myself, so no expert, but presume that it's there to stop feedback loops.

I can't see any obvious reason why you want to send the value down to the child and back up to the parent, but presume the child applies some additional logic.
To me, seems better to apply any additional logic in a service rather than a child component.

I realize the plunker code doesn't have a loop, but the Angular mechanism seems rather simple - just re-checks values at the end of the cycle. Note, **groupingTabValid** in your question code does feedback directly.

Looking at the plunker code as given, structurally the change to age can be handled on the parent. The click event would be `(click)=changeAge(age.value)` and the method (on parent) to handle it

```
changeAge(inputAge) {
  this.newAge = inputAge;
  this.person.age = inputAge;
}
```

Here's a fork of the plunker. [Modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nYcDlqIWqYXSEbFDHbLM?p=preview)
The child component still updates person.age, but no longer causes an error as the value is the same as set on the parent.